# How to use setInterval() properly? - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on some kind of auto slide and I need some help on setInterval().
As far as I know, setInterval() makes functions repeat infinitely so I think setInterval() is what I need. Here is what I am working on:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="background_top" class="slide"></div>
<div id="slidephoto"></div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS

```
#container {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:618px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#background_top {
position:absolute;
background-image:url(images/basvurubg.jpg);
background-size:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:100%;
height:618px;
z-index:0;
margin-left:100%;
}
#slidephoto {
position:absolute;
background-image:url(images/bgtop2.jpg);
background-size:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:100%;
height:618px;
z-index:-1;
left:0%;
}
```

and jQuery

```
$('.slide').delay(5000).load("index.html", function() {
$('.slide').each( function() {
    if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
        $(this).css("left", "150%");
    }
});
$(this).animate({
     left: '-100%'
 }, 500);
 $(this).delay(5000).animate({
     left: '100%'
 }, 550);
 $(this).delay(5000).animate({
     left: '-100%'
 }, 500);
 $(this).delay(5000).animate({
     left: '100%'
 }, 550);

 if ($(this).next().size() > 0) {
     $(this).next().animate({
         left: '0%'
     }, 500);
 } else {
     $(this).prevAll().last().animate({
         left: '0%'
     }, 500);
 }
});
```

The code is working properly and just like what I want. But I want this slide to last forever. And I don't know what to do about it. 
I tried to repeat the animation I want by copying the code on this part. And then I removed the last two (this) part and tried to add setInterval() but did not work:

```
$(this).animate({
 left: '-100%'
 }, 500);
$(this).delay(5000).animate({
 left: '100%'
}, 550);
$(this).delay(5000).animate({
  left: '-100%'
}, 500);
$(this).delay(5000).animate({
 left: '100%'
}, 550);
```

I need this slide animation to last forever.

Comment: please create a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two solution here:

### Option 1 (use `setInterval`):

```js
$('.slide').delay(500).load("index.html", function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  loop(_this);
});

function loop(thisone) {
  var _this = thisone;
  setInterval(function() {
    _this.animate({
      left: '-100%'
    }, 1000);
    _this.delay(1000).animate({
      left: '100%'
    }, 1000);
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 618px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#background_top {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x100);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 618px;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: 100%;
}

#slidephoto {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x200);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 618px;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="background_top" class="slide"></div>
  <div id="slidephoto"></div>
</div>
```

## Option 2 (use `setTimeout`):

```js
$('.slide').delay(500).load("index.html", function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  loop(_this);
});

function loop(thisone) {
  var _this = thisone;
  _this.animate({
    left: '-100%'
  }, 1000);
  _this.delay(1000).animate({
    left: '100%'
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    loop(thisone);
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 618px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#background_top {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/600x600);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 618px;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: 100%;
}

#slidephoto {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/750x750);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 618px;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="background_top" class="slide"></div>
  <div id="slidephoto"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @İbrahimALKAN happy to help